# Can we fetch the Nepali language in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

Can we fetch the Nepali language in Flutter?

In my case, I got something like this

à¤ªà¥à¤°à¤§à¤¾à¤¨à¤®à¤¨à¥à¤¤à¥à¤°à¥ à¤¶à¥à¤°à¤¬à¤¹à¤¾à¤¦à¥à¤° à¤¦à¥à¤à¤µà¤¾ à¤§à¤°à¤¾à¤¨ à¤à¤à¤à¤¦à¥

from the API.
It shows fine on the front end side but on my side, the above text is shown.
How can I overcome that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will return correct nepal or unicode character

```
utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)
```